# Do you make saves against the Web spell as you move through it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150897) I am wondering how exactly the [*web*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web) spell works. It states (emphasis mine):

> Each creature that starts its turn in the webs **or that enters them during its turn** must make a Dexterity saving throw.

I believe that this means that if you are not in the webs and enter them, you must make a save. If you succeeded, exited the webs, and re-entered them, you would have to make *another* save, as you are "entering the webs during your turn".

Unlike many other spells such as *moonbeam*, *web* does not state that the save occurs only the first time you enter them.

**Do you have to make a save for each square of webbing that you enter?**

Comment: The body of your question may have a different answer than the bolded question on the bottom. The body asks about entering and leaving and the bolded question seems to be asking about moving through the web.

Comment: @Alk I am wondering whether moving through the webs counts as entering them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No

All the squares that the web spell affects are the result of a single spell. The wording uses webs (plural) but it starts by specifying:

> You conjure **a mass** of thick, sticky webbing at a point of your choice within range

So there is only one effect, and moving between squares within the web does not trigger any additional saves because the spell does not specify any need to make saves outside of starting within the affect or *entering* on a turn.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that you only *enter* the webs when you go from an unaffected square into the webs and not when you walk from one web square to another?

Comment: @med That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

No, you only have to make one save per turn.

To break down the spell's text: "Each creature ... must make **a** Dexterity saving throw." Once you make your one saving throw, you don't have to roll again, because the creature that is you has already made **a** saving throw.

Comment: I'm unsure, are you saying that if you made a save, left the webs and re-entered them you also wouldn't make a second saving throw?

Comment: Correct.  You already made a save against the spell this turn.  I read it as "each creature who does either of [starts their turn in the web OR enters it] must make a save".  If you start your turn there and make your save, the whole clause has been fulfilled.  Activating the second part of the OR doesn't change anything, because you already did it due to the first part.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, not for just moving through...

The Web spell has up to 4 effects.

Creatures who either start their turn or enter into it on their turn would be subject to;

1. *Lightly Obscured* no Save
2. *Difficult Terrain* no Save
3. *Restrained condition* Dex. Save against spell DC and a Strength check to break free if Dex. Save failed.
4. *2D4 Fire damage* no Save but only affects creatures who start their turn on a space where the webs have been set on fire.

**But**

The language does not state the first time you enter on your turn, so a creature entering and exiting and re-entering the spell would have to make 2 saves against the restrained condition.